# FastAPI post request body, jsonlines of any number of jsons

Tags: python, rest, web, post, fastapi

Using FastAPI requires defining the Request Body. like this

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    catalog_item_number: str
    label: str
```

This accepts only one json per request.
I want to make it accept any number of JSONs in the same body request

```
{"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"}
{"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"}
{"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"}
{"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"}
...etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should only be one json object per request.
To solve this, put the objects into a json array like this:

```
[
  {"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"},
  {"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"},
  {"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"},
  {"catalog_item_number":"xxxxxx", "label": "xxxxx"}
]
```

Then your request could accept this as an `Item[]` type.